# Stop text selection from going outside a div?

Tags: html, css, browser

I am pretty sure i seen sites that make firefox (and other browsers?) select text only within a div and not span across other divs. How do i do that

Comment: Man I have got the same problem, did u find the solution ? Thanks

Comment: ok, never mind found it already posted as an answer for other users. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems giving `overflow: hidden` encloses the text selection in that div only.

Hope it helps

source
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5505944/932473

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](http://javascript.internet.com/page-details/disable-text-selection.html).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>No Select!</title>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                document.onselectstart = function() {return false;} // ie
                document.onmousedown = function() {return false;} // mozilla
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Select me!
    </body>
</html>
```

By the way try to avoid this kind of stuff as it's not cool to prevent visitors from their basic rights!! If someone wants to select a text, they'll know how to do it and there's no way to prevent it.

Comment: maybe the title confused you. i revised it

Comment: you mean when the user presses Ctrl+A?

Comment: There are definitely legitimate reasons for preventing highlighting. For example, I have an image cropper where users drag the mouse but often people drag beyond the edges. It helps make the cropping experience easier but the side-effect was that a whole bunch of outside text was being highlighted when the intent is clearly not that. :-)