# Google Chrome moves div out of document flow when using internal links

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Look at the two links below in Chrome:

Working: http://www.datesphere.com/boards/showthread.php?tid=46

Broken: http://www.datesphere.com/boards/showthread.php?tid=46&pid=345#pid345

Notice how the navigation breadcrumb and "thread rating" section render correctly in the "working" link, but are jammed up under the user panel in the "broken" link. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out why this is happening (asked on mybb.com and a couple other forums, reported a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=77950) to Google Chrome team, etc.) but haven't had any luck, so am hoping Stackoverflow comes through once again.

Here's what I know:

- This only happens in Google Chrome, and as far as I can tell only on permalinked posts where you have an internal link -- pages ending with  "pid=[number]#pid[number]"
- I believe it's happening because the "wrapper" div that starts the content section is being rendered up at the same place as the user panel instead of below it, where it belongs in the document flow.
- Adding a clearing div ("style=clear:both;") before the "content" div fixes the problem in Chrome Developer Tools, but when you add it to the actual code nothing happens.

This is the most baffling and frustrating thing I've come across in html / css. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, and how I might fix it?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: That's quite odd. The HTML appears to be the same and you need to remove both `pid=345` and `#pid345` to get it working correctly again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your culprit.

```
#content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is exactly the reason why you shouldn't use overflow hidden for clearing floats. Anchor links will cause overflowed elements to scroll in certain situations.
Look into [clearfix](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) for clearing floats instead.

Run this javascript in your console for a demonstration on the problem:

```
document.getElementById("content").scrollTop = 0
```

Comment: I freaking love you, that solved a problem I've been struggling with for an embarrassingly long time. I tried entering that line into the console to no avail (I have much to learn), but thank you for solving this problem!

Comment: How... why... why is this a thing?! I mean... surely Chrome developers must have had a good reason to FRICKIN REARRANGE MY HTML WITHOUT TELLING ME. Is this documented anywhere? Out of curiosity, how did you figure this out?